# What are the C# equivalent of these C++ structs

Tags: c#, c++, struct, marshalling

```
typedef union _Value {
    signed char    c; 
    unsigned char  b; 
    signed short   s; 
    unsigned short w; 
    signed long    l; 
    unsigned long  u; 
    float          f; 
    double        *d; 
    char          *p; 
} Value;


typedef struct _Field {
 WORD    nFieldId;
 BYTE    bValueType;
 Value Value;
} Field;


typedef struct _Packet {
 WORD    nMessageType;
 WORD    nSecurityType;
 BYTE    bExchangeId;
 BYTE    bMarketCenter;
 int     iFieldCount;
 char    cSymbol[20];
    Field FieldArr[1];

} Packet;
```

What are the C# equivalent of these C++ structs?

I am migrating some code from C++ to C# and having problems to migrate these structures. I had tried a few things but I always ended up having marshalling problems.

Comment: For the union, see http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/60150e7b-665a-49a2-8e2e-2097986142f3/c-equivalent-to-c-union?forum=csharplanguage

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm assuming the 'char' is being used as an 8 bit number, if so, then here are you're mappings:

```
signed char    c; -> SByte    c; 
unsigned char  b; -> Byte     b;
signed short   s; -> Int16    s;
unsigned short w; -> UInt16   w;
signed long    l; -> Int32    l;
unsigned long  u; -> UInt32   u;
float          f; -> Single   f; (though 'float' still works)
double        *d; -> Double   d; (was this meant to be a pointer???)
char          *p; -> String   s; (assuming its a string here, in the marshaling you can tell it whether it is ASCII or wide char format)
```

With this info it should be relatively easy to translate those strucutres (just make sure you keep them as a struct and give it the attribute "[System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayout(System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential)]", which will make sure that the marshaller keeps all the data in the same order.

Also, I recommend looking through both the classes and attributes in System.Runtime.InteropServices as they do provide quite a few methods for automating marshaling of data to c/c++ code (and it doesn't require "unsafe" c# code either).

Comment: `signed long` and `unsigned long` should map to `IntPtr` and `UIntPtr`, respectively. `double*` in C++ will map to `IntPtr` or `double*` in C#, the latter is obviously only allow in unsafe code. The `StructLayout` attribute can specify the `CharSet`.

Comment: `System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Sequential` seems inappropriate for a union, which should have `System.Runtime.InteropServices.LayoutKind.Explicit`.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the other posts already have great information, I thought I would share a quick tip. I had to go through this kind of issue recently. It may be obvious but if you own the code to both sides of the interface I found that commenting out all but the one fields and making sure that works and then adding them back slowly one by one was a much safer way to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468(VS.71).aspx) on marshaling structs with PInvoke.

The key is using the `StructLayout` attribute to ensure that the struct is treated properly by PInvoke, and the `MarshalAs` attribute for types that don't line up exactly.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention; I've already have StructLayout defined on my C# equivalents and I don't want to use PInvoke. Basically data is incoming as bytes from a socket and I want to marshal them into my c# structures.

Comment: If the data comes in from the network, I'd just declare the fixed part of the Packet type as a C# struct, and then use a BinaryReader over the network stream to read the remaining data. Dealing with variable length structs is nontrivial in C#.

Answer (score 0):

Back in .Net 2.0 days i also had a network socket and to convert the byte stream into a meaningful structure. At this time there was the only solution to do it by hand with [BitConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.aspx) and [Buffer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.aspx) class.

Unfortunately i couldn't find the example on the web again. So i stripped down my old class (gosh, this looks so old and ugly...). Maybe due to strip down, there are some small typo errors within it, but it should give you a good idea on how to accomplish the problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace VehicleSpeedTracer
{
    public class Datagram
    {
        //Offsets im ByteArray
        private const int SizeOffset = 0;
        private const int TimeOffset = SizeOffset + sizeof(uint);
        private const int SpeedOffset = TimeOffset + sizeof(double);
        private const int UnitOffset = SpeedOffset + sizeof(char);
        private const int UnitMaxSize = (int)MaxSize - UnitOffset;

        //Daten Current
        public const uint MaxSize = 128;
        public TimeSpan CurrentTime;
        public double CurrentSpeed;
        public string Unit;

        public uint Size
        {
            get { return MaxSize - (uint)UnitMaxSize + (uint)Unit.Length; }
        }

        public Datagram()
        {
        }

        public Datagram(Datagram Data)
        {
            CurrentTime = Data.CurrentTime;
            CurrentSpeed = Data.CurrentSpeed;
            Unit = Data.Unit;
        }

        public Datagram(byte[] RawData)
        {
            CurrentTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(GetDouble(RawData, TimeOffset));
            CurrentSpeed = GetDouble(RawData, SpeedOffset);
            Unit = GetString(RawData, UnitOffset, (int)(GetUInt(RawData, SizeOffset) - UnitOffset));
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return this.CurrentTime.Hours.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" +
                    this.CurrentTime.Minutes.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + ":" +
                    this.CurrentTime.Seconds.ToString().PadLeft(2, '0') + "." +
                    this.CurrentTime.Milliseconds.ToString().PadLeft(3, '0') + "  " +
                    this.Unit;
        }

        public static implicit operator byte[](Datagram Data)
        {
            byte[] RawData;
            RawData = new byte[Data.Size];
            SetUInt(RawData, SizeOffset, Data.Size);
            SetDouble(RawData, TimeOffset, Data.CurrentTime.TotalDays);
            SetDouble(RawData, SpeedOffset, Data.CurrentSpeed);
            SetString(RawData, UnitOffset, Data.Unit);

            return RawData;
        }

        #region Utility Functions
        // utility:  get a uint from the byte array
        private static uint GetUInt(byte[] aData, int Offset)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToUInt32(aData, Offset);
        }

        // utility:  set a uint into the byte array
        private static void SetUInt(byte[] aData, int Offset, uint Value)
        {
            byte[] buint = BitConverter.GetBytes(Value);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(buint, 0, aData, Offset, buint.Length);
        }

        // utility:  get a ushort from the byte array
        private static ushort GetUShort(byte[] aData, int Offset)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToUInt16(aData, Offset);
        }

        // utility:  set a ushort into the byte array
        private static void SetUShort(byte[] aData, int Offset, int Value)
        {
            byte[] bushort = BitConverter.GetBytes((short)Value);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bushort, 0, aData, Offset, bushort.Length);
        }

        // utility:  get a double from the byte array
        private static double GetDouble(byte[] aData, int Offset)
        {
            return BitConverter.ToDouble(aData, Offset);
        }

        // utility:  set a double into the byte array
        private static void SetDouble(byte[] aData, int Offset, double Value)
        {
            byte[] bushort = BitConverter.GetBytes(Value);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(bushort, 0, aData, Offset, bushort.Length);
        }

        // utility:  get a unicode string from the byte array
        private static string GetString(byte[] aData, int Offset, int Length)
        {
            String sReturn = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(aData, Offset, Length);
            return sReturn;
        }

        // utility:  set a unicode string in the byte array
        private static void SetString(byte[] aData, int Offset, string Value)
        {
            byte[] arr = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Value);
            Buffer.BlockCopy(arr, 0, aData, Offset, arr.Length);
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public delegate void DatagramEventHandler(object sender, DatagramEventArgs e);

    public class DatagramEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Datagram Data;

        public DatagramEventArgs(Datagram Data)
        {
            this.Data = Data;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 This method is really dated now. C# 3.0 (may have been available in earlier versions, I only started in 3) has excellent support for mostly automating translation of data. I haven't had to do anything complex myself to get any c function working in c#, even structures containing variable length strings are easy to do.

Comment: Yes, for a function you want to access by DLLImport this is true. But if you have a byte[] (e.g. from a socket) there isn't such a thing (as far as i know).