# Which datatype is used for unsigned char in C#?

Tags: c#, c++

I have a c++ application. In that application one of the function is returning `unsigned char` value. I want to convert that function into C# code. But, I don't have enough knowledge about c++ programming. I want to know what datatype would be placed against **c++ unsigned char** in **C#**.

The c++ function is look like this

```
unsigned char getValue(string s)
{
    //SOME CODE HERE
}
```

Comment: thank you all to giving  me quick answer. all answers are correct and helpful for me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The equivalent of `unsigned char` in C# is `byte`.

```
byte getValue(string s)
{

}
```

Second option: if you use unsigned char as a character storage, you should use `char`:

```
char getValue(string s)
{

}
```

---

You have to remember, that C++ treats characters and 8-byte values equally. So, for instance in C++:

```
'A' + 'B' == 65 + 66 == 65 + 'B' == 'A' + 66
```

You have to check from the context, whether the `unsigned char` is a character or a number. From string being passed as a parameter, one can *guess*, that the function processes characters so mostly probably you want a `char` C# type.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the `byte` type. Also, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333302/what-are-the-c-sharp-equivalent-of-these-c-structs) has additional mappings if you need those.

If your `C#` Code is supposed to treat the value as a *character*, then the `char` type is what you want. The reason why we have been suggesting *byte* is because we are assuming you want to treat the value as an `8-bit` integer.

Answer (score 3):

```
C++ unsigned char = C# byte
C++ char = C# sbyte
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `char`. A `char` in C# is neither signed or unsigned. It is 16 bit value.

If you do not want to retain the character, but the actual binary number, then you should choose the `byte`, that is a unsigned integer number, just like the `unsigned char` in c++.

See also: [What is an unsigned char?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75191/what-is-an-unsigned-char)

Comment: so, is my function returning ascii byte or any alphabetic character?

Comment: @Nimesh, Your function is returning an 8-bit value, which your program can choose to interpret however it chooses to.

Comment: Both. So to make a choise, we need to find out the actual needed datatype, so we need the body of the method. If the method returns, for example, the first character from the given string, then the return type is `char`. if it will return the number of elements in the string, `byte` should be better (besides `int`).